# Overlay Rectangle on a ListPlot

Tags: graphics

I have a `ListPlot` of 100 data points in the range of 0 and 1. Now I'm trying to find a way to overlay (four) rectangles onto the `ListPlot` in 0.25 steps horizontally. Essentially I just have `BinLists` and try to visualize the Bins on the `ListPlot` with rectangles.

I drew a nice little picture with paint (since I can't draw it in mathematica yet :)) which hopefully makes it a little more clearer..I only drew three rectangles..

[image]

It seems somehow complicated to me and I don't get it to work (except with paint ^^), can someone help me out?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [GridLines](https://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/GridLines.html) and its option `GridLinesStyle` :) I don't have _Mathematica_ right now but by playing around with these two you should be able to have what you want :)

Comment: Try `Epilog->{Rectangle[...]}` too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**1.** Use `Epilog`:

```
ListPlot[RandomInteger[50, 100],
 Epilog -> {EdgeForm[{Thick, Gray}], Opacity[.2], Blue, 
     Rectangle @@@ Thread[{Thread[{0, Range[0, 40, 10]}], 
                           Thread[{100, Range[10, 50, 10]}]}]}]
(* or use `MapThread[Rectangle, {Thread[{0, Range[0, 40, 10]}], 
  Thread[{100, Range[10, 50, 10]}]}]` instead of `Rectangle@@@Thread[...]`  *)
```

[image]

**2.** Use `GridLines`:

```
ListPlot[RandomInteger[50, 100], GridLines -> {{100}, Range[0, 50, 10]}]
```

[image]

**3.** Overlay `ListPlot` with `Histogram` using a constant height specification:

```
data = RandomInteger[50, 100];
bins = Range[0, 50, 10];
(* use a constant function for the third argument of `Histogram` *)
Show[ListPlot[data], Histogram[data, {bins}, 100 & /@ # &, BarOrigin -> Left, 
    ChartStyle -> Opacity[.3]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Works! Thank you